# Firebase rules to restrict collection based on uid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firebase Rules for i want to write the following rule

If the user email  is in the users list (in the Authentication Tab) then only he should be allowed to read the collection defined by his uid after authentication.

For Example : If the useremail is abc@gmail.com and uid is 0M0drKmwJCWal7XHjHKuPz3rhHQ2

1. User should be listed in abc@gmail.com
2. As his uid is "0M0drKmwJCWal7XHjHKuPz3rhHQ2" then he should be allowed to read/write on the collection by the name "0M0drKmwJCWal7XHjHKuPz3rhHQ2" only.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /users/{userId} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: The rules look fine for that use-case at first glance, and seem to match with the documentation on [content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#cloud-firestore_2). What is the problem you have with these rules? Any error message?

Comment: I am unable to restrict this to the collection , which is the uid .It should only access "0M0drKmwJCWal7XHjHKuPz3rhHQ2" collection only.

Comment: "I am unable" is not very easy to act on. Can you edit your question to show the code that doesn't do what you expect it to do?  If your access is unexpectedly getting denied, be sure to prove in the code that it meets the requirement of your rules - i.e. log the UID of the current user right before you access the database - and show the output of that too.